# Rxjava, Retrofit response body doesn't get the right answer?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

My code like this:

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    // set your desired log level
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();


    this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    // retrofit with custom client


    this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetUtil.getServerBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    this.apiService = retrofit.create(ApiEndpoints.class);
}



public Call<String> downloadImageCall(String uri){
    return apiService.rxGetImageCall(uri);
}
```

The retrofit is like:

```
 @GET
 Call<String> rxGetImageCall(@Url String imageUrl);
```

When i run my code :
        String url="";

```
   Call<String> downCall =     downloadImageCall(url);
                    try {
                        Response<String> mresponse =  downCall.execute();
                        String info  =mresponse.body();
                        LogHelper.i("final info: "+info);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The data returned from the server is like :

"**Please** contact the administrator".

However in the above code, The info is just  "**Please**"

I am confused about it, where is wrong about my code?

Comment: What does the HttpLoggingInterceptor intercept? As a side-note: Why would you use the call-adapter for RxJava but don't use Observables as return-type instead of Call<>?

Comment: HttpLoggingInterceptor, I just want to print the log(request and response). The reason I don't want to use Observable, because the result is not so important ,even it return error, its  ok for me. So I just use call,but my problem is : currently I can only get part of the result.

Comment: So, is the result of the body-interception (log) the same as mresponse.body()? It is hard to answer, because I can not check your server response.

Comment: the result of body-interception is different for mresponse.body.you can try when url is "  http://javascript.info/tutorial/hello-world  ".

Comment: Please have a look at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/80f38b31a1bc15a71850c61fddd23b23. I don't get why you are using retrofit or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Hans Wurst, Thanks for your reply. My code is a little different from yours. For some reason I can not give my real url ,but I give another url ,it has the same problem. I wrote an example and address is https://github.com/fhlkm/RetrofitDemo, please see the "final info "value.  Because I am using android, it could be a bug of android or retrofit.Please check. Thanks

Comment: My knowledge is limited for retrofit, but I think I found out what the problem is. The downloaded stream (byte) has been read with Gson and tried to convert to String. You need to return ResponseBody. Maybe there are better ways to do it. Please have a look at https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/fa6f14c85962d35e241599d60942b586

Comment: Hi @Hans, You are right, after I change it to ResponseBody, I can get all of the information. I will post my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on @Hans answer, I changed it to Responsebody, it works. But I don't know why `"Call <String>"`   doesn't work.  Feel free to post your answer.

This is my code:

```
  @GET
 Call<ResponseBody> rxGetImageCall(@Url String imageUrl);


 public Call<ResponseBody> downloadImageCall(String uri){
  return apiService.rxGetImageCall(uri);
  }

 Call<ResponseBody> mbody = mOperation.downloadContentDetail("http://javascript.info/tutorial/hello-world");

                        try {
                            Response<ResponseBody> mResponse =  mbody.execute();
                            InputStream mStream =mResponse.body().byteStream();
                            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(mStream);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            int result = bis.read();
                            while(result != -1) {
                                buf.write((byte) result);
                                result = bis.read();
                            }
                            LogHelper.i("result 1" + buf.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: Looks like there is no Converter for Response -> String. You can implement your own StringConverter. Please have a look at: https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/ed9bb60e0d0f8799bf9caa98b5df8950

Comment: Thanks @Hans, it is perfect